# Other language Translate riddle

Tags: riddle

1)  ಬಿಳಿಯ ಪೊರೆ ಬಿಡುವ ನಾಗವಲ್ಲ ! ಗುಂಡಗಿರುವೆ ಗೋಲಿಯ ಗುಂಡಲ್ಲ! ದೇಹವು ಮಡಿಕೆಗಳಿಂದ ಕೂಡಿರುವುದು , ಕುಂಬಳ ಕಾಯಲ್ಲ

7) ಅಂಕು ಡೊಂಕಿನ ಮರ, ಕಚ್ಚಿದವರ ಬಾಯಿಗೆ , ಉಚ್ಚಿ ಹುಯ್ಯುವ ಮರ

3) ಮುಳ್ಳು ಮುಳ್ಳು ಮರದಲ್ಲಿ , ಮುತ್ತು ಮುತ್ತು ಕಾಯಿ

4) ಚಿಕ್ಕ ಚಿಕ್ಕ ಪೆಟ್ಟಿಗೆ , ಚಿನ್ನದ ಪೆಟ್ಟಿಗೆ , ಮುಚ್ಚಿ ತೆಗೆದರೆ ಮುನ್ನೂರು ಪೆಟ್ಟಿಗೆ

Decode 1734 eatables in English to start the _ _ _ _ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) ಬಿಳಿಯ ಪೊರೆ ಬಿಡುವ ನಾಗವಲ್ಲ ! ಗುಂಡಗಿರುವೆ ಗೋಲಿಯ ಗುಂಡಲ್ಲ! ದೇಹವು ಮಡಿಕೆಗಳಿಂದ ಕೂಡಿರುವುದು , ಕುಂಬಳ ಕಾಯಲ್ಲ

> **Garlic** (I am not a snake which leaves its white scurf, I am round but not a ball, body is like a pot, but I am not pumpkin)

7) ಅಂಕು ಡೊಂಕಿನ ಮರ, ಕಚ್ಚಿದವರ ಬಾಯಿಗೆ , ಉಚ್ಚಿ ಹುಯ್ಯುವ ಮರ

> **Sugarcane** (Curvy tree, if you bite it, it spills its urine!)

3) ಮುಳ್ಳು ಮುಳ್ಳು ಮರದಲ್ಲಿ , ಮುತ್ತು ಮುತ್ತು ಕಾಯಿ

> **Lemon** (Good hen, has laid eggs in thorns)

4) ಚಿಕ್ಕ ಚಿಕ್ಕ ಪೆಟ್ಟಿಗೆ , ಚಿನ್ನದ ಪೆಟ್ಟಿಗೆ , ಮುಚ್ಚಿ ತೆಗೆದರೆ ಮುನ್ನೂರು ಪೆಟ್ಟಿಗೆ

> **Pomegranate** (Small box, gold box, when closed and opened three hundred boxes)

Decode 1734 eatables in English to start the _ _ _ _ ?

> By watching alphabet positions in each riddle 1734 means *GAME* (Thanks to @IanMacDonald 7).

Comment: correct  answer 1734 ?

Comment: The second one in the list should actually be numbered 7, not 2. Are the words in parentheses included in the text, or are they your guesses to the riddle answers?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase your response to my question?

Comment: @IanMacDonald 7 is correct ..

Comment: I’m not sure how 7 answers the question. It seems to me that the riddles posed in each will provide one letter to the final four blanks. If I had to guess, they should spell “game”.

Comment: In future Umar, could you put your answer in a spoiler?

Comment: Spoiler? I'm unable to understand what you are trying to say @samm82

Comment: Begin each line with ">!" to hide the answer until someone hovers over it/clicks it. It stops people from accidentally spoiling the answer if they want to try and solve it. (See other riddles for examples of this)